# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que el título tape los iconos editar/mover/eliminar? HTML, JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy colocando reglas *CSS* para solucionar el problema de que el texto del título de cada módulo deje de sobreponerse encima de los íconos *editar/mover/eliminar* pero sin dar con la solución.

[image: Imagen referencia]

```html
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">
    <h5 class="panel-title">
      <i class="zalv-arrow-circle-right"></i>
      <span contenteditable="true" id="moduleTitle_2">Estoy destinado a ser exitos en mi vida. Sin importar lo que suceda nunca me rendiré.</span>
    </h5>
    <div class="pull-right objective_page">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Editar" data-backdrop="false" class="moduleEdit" data-id="2">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Mover">
        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Eliminar" id="moduleDeleteId_2" onclick="zalvadora.create_course.check_element({is_object_page: 1 , chapter_id: 2, course_id: 2, parent_id: 0,content_type:'chapter',chaptertype:1},'Objetivo','Unidad')">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Es difícil replicar la situación ya que no tenemos todos los estilos, pero yo te recomiendo lo siguiente: mete la etiqueta h5 en un div, y haz que ese div ocupe un 80% del contenedor padre, y el otro div (destinado a las acciones) que ocupe el 20% restante. Así evitaras que se superpongan los textos y los iconos.

Comment: Veo que usas las clases de bootstrap. Podrias agregar los plugins al snippet para que funcione como en la imagen y hacer pruebas? yo dividiria cada row en una columna de 10 y otra de 2, para que no se superpongan. Colocaria el texto en la columna de 10 y los botones en la columna de 2. Le podes configurar el overflow por si el texto se desborda, o darle un tamaño dinamico.

Comment: @AgustinG. implementé tu solución pero aún no logro evitar el problema. El overflow se lo aplico a la h5 podría ser?

Comment: perdon, estoy en el campo y estoy viendo ahora esto. Cual es el problema que aún no logras evitar? (el tema del overflow era para que los ``contenteditable`` queden en una sola linea, es decir, evitar el salto de línea. Lo de las columnas que se pisaban lo pudiste solventar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Acá agregue bootstrap y font awesome para probar.
> Agregué la clase `row`al primer div, y luego dividí en dos columnas `col-10` (para esto cree un nuevo div que rodea al `h5`) y `col-2` (acá usé el div `pull_right` que ya existía). De esta manera siempre se mantendran separados.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class=" row panel-heading text-center">
   <div class='col-10'>
     <h5 class="panel-title">
      <i class="zalv-arrow-circle-right"></i>
      <span contenteditable="true" id="moduleTitle_2">Estoy destinado a ser exitos en mi vida. Sin importar lo que suceda nunca me rendiré.</span>
     </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2 pull-right objective_page">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Editar" data-backdrop="false" class="moduleEdit" data-id="2">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Mover">
        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Eliminar" id="moduleDeleteId_2" onclick="zalvadora.create_course.check_element({is_object_page: 1 , chapter_id: 2, course_id: 2, parent_id: 0,content_type:'chapter',chaptertype:1},'Objetivo','Unidad')">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu valioso aporte ahora los iconos se movieron hacia arriba